# How to properly handle the updating of constructors in a poorly setup .NET unit test project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq, mstest

**TL;DR:** I inherited an old .NET project where modifying a controller's constructor broke 307 unit tests and caused 90 classes to not build in the unit test project. Each `[TestMethod]` was initialized individually instead of using `[TestInitialize]`. I want to rewrite the tests to avoid updating all 307 constructors (and around 90 classes) to make it easy to maintain for future developers that come across it. I attempted using AutoFac for dependency injection but am unsure if it's the right approach. Looking for guidance on how to handle this situation effectively, and am open to any ideas / solutions.

##### Background

I was given an old ASP.NET project that required some modifications. One of the changes I had to make involved modifying a controller's constructor (unavoidable). However, this modification resulted in 307 broken constructors in the unit test project. It's unclear why these constructors were written this way, but it is crucial for all 307 tests to build and pass. While these tests are still valid within the code's context, they were supposedly written by someone who used a special multi-line find and replace tool to initialize every test instance, rather than utilizing .NET's `[TestInitialize]` action in each class.

The unit testing project comprises around 90 classes that need fixing. It appears that a previous developer encountered a similar issue, as all 307 constructors have the last dependency set to null without any initialization elsewhere (indicating the lack of new tests).

I would like to rewrite these tests in a way that doesn't require updating 307 individual constructors every time the controller's constructor changes. While initializing the constructor and its components once in each class is an option, it would involve a significant amount of work given the number of classes. Ideally, I would like to abstract the initialization process using a TestHelper and TestInitializer class. However, I'm facing difficulties in implementing this solution.

##### My Attempted Solution

To address this situation, I attempted to use dependency injection with AutoFac. My approach involved creating a RandomHandlerTestInitializer class to define mock objects for the dependencies used in the tests. Then, I created a RandomHandlerTestHelper class that inherited from RandomHandlerTestInitializer to handle the common setup and initialization of dependencies.

In the RandomHandlerTestHelper class, I used AutoFac's ContainerBuilder to register the dependencies and the updated RandomHandler with the modified constructor. I also defined methods to resolve dependencies from the container and dispose of the container when necessary.

For the unit tests, I utilized the RandomHandlerTestHelper class to create an instance of RandomHandler and perform the necessary test actions.

However, I'm uncertain if my implementation is the appropriate way to handle this situation using dependency injection, particularly with AutoFac. I'm open to learning and trying alternative solutions or frameworks like Moq. Therefore, I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on a more concrete and effective approach to address this issue.

```
public class RandomHandlerTestInitializer
{
   public static Mock<DbContext> _dbContextMock { get; set; }
   public static Mock<UserManager<AspNetIdentityUser>> _userManagerRepositoryMock { get; set; }
   public static Mock<IUserRepository> _userRepositoryMock { get; set; }
}
```

```
[TestClass]
public class RandomHandlerTestHelper : RandomHandlerTestInitializer
{
    public static IContainer _container;

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Registering the dependencies
         builder.RegisterInstance(_portalDbContextMock.Object)
             .As<PortalDbContext()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
         builder.RegisterInstance(_userManagerRepositoryMock.Object)
             .As<UserManager<AspNetIdentityUser()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
         builder.RegisterInstance(_userRepositoryMock.Object)
             .As<IUserRepository>()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
         

         // Registering the RandomHandler with the updated constructor
         builder.RegisterType<RandomHandler>()
             .WithParameter("_userRepositoryMock", null)
             .AsSelf()
             .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

         _container = builder.Build();
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void AssemblyCleanup()
    {
       DisposeContainer();
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        //Resolving dependencies and assigning to class fields
        _portalDbContextMock = new Mock<PortalDbContext>();
        _userManagerRepositoryMock = new Mock<UserManager<AspNetIdentityUser>>();
        _userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

        //If there's any common initialization it will be done here
        _userRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.RandomFunction(It.IsAny<List<string>>()))
            .Returns(new List<UserPermissions>());
    }

    public RandomHandler CreateRandomHandler()
    {
        // Resolving the RandomHandler from the container
        return _container.Resolve<RandomHandler>();
    }

    public static void DisposeContainer()
    {
        _container?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {    
        //Arrange
        //Call a method from RandomHandlerTestHelper or access its properties
        Mock<DbContext> dbContextMock = RandomHandlerTestInitializer._dbContextMock;
        Mock<IUserRepository> userRepositoryMock = RandomHandlerTestInitializer._userRepositoryMock;
        
        //Act
        RandomHandlerTestHelper helper = new RandomHandlerTestHelper();
        RandomHandler randomHandler = helper.CreateRandomHandler();
        
        //Assert
        
    }
}
```